# GLXBad Drawable error

Tags: python, wxpython, numpy

When I run a Python script I get this error after installing all dependencies:

```
The program 'python2' received an X Window System error.
```

What are the possibilities?

[Link](http://pastebin.com/T7bszanr) to the python script.

Comment: An addition to description of errorpython2:2608): Gdk-WARNING **: gdkdrawable-x11.c:952 drawable is not a pixmap or window
The program 'python2' received an X Window System error.

Comment: I can't tell anything much based on your pasted script, since it isn't a self-contained example (`from rubiks import *`?), although the error sounds like a failure to attach to a valid OpenGL context. Can you run any other OpenGL demos, e.g. [these](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/context/tutorials/index.xhtml)?